# Ruby regexp does not catch targeted expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using a validation to reject any string containing `<p>` or `&lt;p&gt;` (equivalent in html characters of the p html tag).

I tried with a string that did contain it and strings with `<p>` tag are rejected but not those with `&lt;p&gt;`

```
validates_format_of :message_content,
                      :with => /\A((?!<p>).)*\z/i,
                      :message => "pb1"             


validates_format_of :message_content,
                      :with => /\A((?!&lt;p&gt;).)*\z/i,
                      :message => "pb2"
```

Should I escape some of the special characters of `!&lt;p&gt;` ,which could create issues for the regexp ? How ?

Comment: how about using a  [custom validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations) and gsubbing the escaped html entities before performing the regex?

Comment: Is this a rails question? If so tag it appropriately.

Comment: @maxpleaner How would you do this? You mean you would use gsub to replace the html characters by <p> before enforcing the regex ? Seems overkill.can't i just validate these html entity characters are not found by the regex?

Comment: I see no need for escaping characters. Doesn't `r = Regexp.new("<p>|&lt;p&gt;") #=> /<p>|&lt;p&gt;/` work (i.e., `str !~ r`)?

Comment: @CarySwoveland i just know my validate does not work , and as there is the presence of special characters so i assumed maybe but only maybe they were the cause of the failure

Comment: `"!&lt;p&gt;" =~ /\A((?!&lt;p&gt;).)*\z/i #=> nil`. Cannot reproduce. Please provide a [mcve]!

Comment: I think you should take a different approach using the `sanitize` helper. Insert something like `before_validation :sanitize_content, :on => :create` and then in your `sanitize_content` method use `ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(field, tags)` configured appropriately. Your meager attempt at preventing `p` tags is easily fooled (e.g. by whitespace `< p>`)

Comment: ^^ This. I'm 95% sure you're asking the wrong question here. Trying to block HTML input via a regex validation screams of bad design; there's almost certainly a better solution to your problem.

Comment: thanks people, will try to digest all your comments in 3 hours from now. and will answer and try to provide better ways to check/test this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to validate that a regexp is not match. You will have simplier regexp that are easier to implement :

```
validates :message_content, format: { without: /<p>/i, message: 'pb1' }
validates :message_content, format: { without: /&lt;p&gt;/i, message: 'pb2' }
```